# Does one "speak" a sign language?

Tags: word-usage

Is "speak" the correct verb to use for sign languages? Or does "speak" only refer to vocalised languages?

> I speak BSL

I think I would use "speak" or "use" as a layman, but I'd be interested in which verb the Deaf community uses.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information KannE. I was interested in which verb the Deaf community might use in English (rather than any given sign language), but your comment is interesting nonetheless. The ASL page you linked is nicely written, do you happen to know of a similar page for BSL?

Comment: @KannE: You should post that information in an answer, rather than in comments on the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the meaning of  [speak](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/speak) is:

> - To convey by nonverbal means: His eyes spoke volumes. (The Free Dictionary)

- To speak  is commonly use to refer to sign language

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak%20sign%20language%2Ctalk%20sign%20language&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeak%20sign%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalk%20sign%20language%3B%2Cc0): speak, talk sign language:

> - Cobb, ***who can read and [speak](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=YX_daEhlnbsC&pg=PA880&dq=%22speak%20sign%20language%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=-dqfVYHeE4bT0AS596awBA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAjgU#v=onepage&q=%22speak%20sign%20language%22&f=false) sign language (which he learned from his deaf father)***, has been assigned by the department to assist Tess in the field as her investigator and interpreter when she questions suspects in a case. Stories relate  ...(Encyclopedia of Television Shows, 1925 through 2010, 2d ed.
>     Di Vincent Terrace)
> - ... competency” as described above. ***Hearing children of deaf signers often [speak](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=Qzt86YGwWE8C&pg=PA63&dq=%22speak%20sign%20language%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=ydyfVZalDIXD0gSxhLnYBA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22speak%20sign%20language%22&f=false) sign language extremely fluently***, suggesting that there is no neurophysiological reason for it to be difficult to be fluent in 3. (Artificial Sight: Basic Research, Biomedical Engineering, and Clinical Advances)

Comment: Many people who write about the Deaf Community do not participate in it and should have asked the same question that the original OP is asking. I'll write a full explanation to the question in the morning, but the answer, in short, is no, you do not speak a signed language. You sign a signed language.

Comment: Forgot to add that I am an American Sign Language/ English interpreter.

Comment: Adding **use sign language** to the Ngram search shows that it is much more common than **speak** or **talk**. (Perhaps not surprisingly, "sign sign language" doesn't appear at all. But other uses of "sign" as the verb may be common.)

Comment: @ChristineGK: Did you ever end up writing your own answer to this question? It'd be a shame if your perspective languished only in the comments of another answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I speak BSL.
>   I sign BSL.
>   I use BSL.

These are the idiomatic collocations you can choose from.

Answer (score -2):

It shouldn't be speak sign language it should be use or sign sign language because you don't really speak it as you don't use your voice.